# git-gui on OSX: why does access to context menu now require control key?

Tags: macos, contextmenu, git-gui

I could have sworn that, on OSX, the git-gui context menu that offers options like stage-lines and stage-hunk was always accessible via a right mouse button click but as of today it seems to require the use of a control key as well.

I haven't updated any software, so I am not sure what has changed in my setup that caused this behaviour change.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using an Apple mouse, you may need to (re)enable secondary clicking in System Preferences > Mouse.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your suggestion however I am just using the touch pad on the MacBook Air and it doesn't seem to have such a configuration option

Comment: Your question mentions a "right mouse button click"? What action are you actually doing? There's a similar option on the Trackpad preference pane, I believe.

Comment: I realised that I have always been using 2-finger right mouse button click to get the context menu and had been doing it without realising what I was doing. I recently had to use a Windows laptop with a "normal" right mouse button which needed just a single finger click, then switched back to OSX and then took the Windows behaviour back to OSX without realising.

Sorry for the noise!